# Existence of equivalent norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, equivalent-metrics

Let $L$ be a normed space with norm $\|\cdot\|_1: L\to \mathbf{R}$.
Let $T$ be a linear invertible operator on $L$ such that $\|T^n x\|_1 < c \|x\|_1$ for all $x\in L$ and $n\in \mathbf{N}$.
Show that there is a norm $\|\cdot\|_2: L\to \mathbf{R}$ equivalent to norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ such that $\| Tx\|_2=\|x\|_2$ for all $x\in L$.

My thought is to consider $\|\cdot\|_2: L\to \mathbf{R}$ such that

$\|x\|_2=\|x\|_1 + \sup_{n\in \mathbf{N}} \|T^n x\|_1$

I have proven equivalence of the two norms but I am finding it uneasy proving that $\|T\|_2=1$.

Any help would be appreciated. Is my thought in track?
Thanks

Comment: The inequality in the hypothesis can never hold when $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks, what if we relax the inequality. That is $\|T^n x\|_1\leq c \| x\|_1$?

Comment: I have given a  counter-example in my answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't see it until after I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality in the hypothesis can never hold when $x=0$ so I will change $x \in L$ to $x\in L\setminus \{0\}$.

The assertion is  false. If $T=\frac 1 2 I$ then the hypothesis is satisfied with $c=\frac  3 4$ but there is no norm $\|.\|_2$ such that $\|Tx\|_2=\|x\|_2$ for all $x$.